# ArgumentException: This object does not have a Name property

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wcf

I encountered this error:

> This object does not have a Name property, please use the other
>   contructor.

I am calling data from a WCF to populate a listview. I don't completely understand the error or why it is happening?

**WPF**

```
public async Task LoadTrucks()
{
    TruckServiceClient TSC = new TruckServiceClient();
    try
    {
        var trucks = await TSC.GetTrucksAsync();
        foreach (var truck in trucks)
        lbTrucks.Items.Add(new ListBoxViewItem<RTrucks>(truck));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

**WCF**

```
public List<RTrucks> GetTrucks()
{
    List<RTrucks> r = new List<RTrucks>();
    List<RTrucks> e;
    using (TruckDb db = new TruckDb())
    {
        e = db.RTrucks.Where(x => x.Id != null).ToList();
        foreach (var a in e)
        {
            var truck = new RTrucks()
            {
                Id = a.Id,
                ChassisManufacturer = a.ChassisManufacturer,
                ChassisModel = a.ChassisModel,
                PhaseId = a.PhaseId,
                PhaseStatusId = a.PhaseStatusId,
                QuoteId = a.QuoteId
            };
            r.Add(truck);
        }
        return r;
    }
}
```

Comment: But you can tell us where it is happening right?

Comment: Yes where I am adding the item.. `lbTrucks.Items.Add(new ListBoxViewItem<RTrucks>(truck));` @oguzozgul

Comment: Have you tried following the *"use the other constructor"* instructions that the error has provided?

Comment: no I haven't tried using the other one, excuse me I have a basic knowledge of what a constructor is. But I don't know what other constructor to use.. I have tried this method exactly when populating combo boxes but I receive this error with the listbox. @MikeEason

Comment: Is ListBoxViewItem your class? If yes, please share the code of that class. If it is your class, add a public string Name {get; set;} property to it and set it in the constructor

Comment: yes I didn't focus on that class! you can post it as an answer and I will accept! @OguzOzgul thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list view throws this exception because you are trying to add an instance of the following class to the list view, and that class does not have a a Name property

```
ListBoxViewItem<RTrucks>
```

Please add the following property to your ListBoxViewItem class and set it's value in the constructor by using either Id or other properties of the truck instance passed in:

```
public class ListBoxViewItem<T>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ListBoxViewItem(T tInstance)
    {
        .... // current implementation
        Name = <set the name using tInstance>;
    }
}
```